# Improving an Enum-to-Combobox binding (using MarkupExtension)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, member

I'm trying to simplify at maximum the binding of Enums to ComboBoxes.

Among multiple solutions (ObjectDataProvider, Converter...) I opted for the following MarkupExtension :

```
public class EnumSource : MarkupExtension
{

    public class EnumMember
    {
        public string Display { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Display;
        }
    }


    private readonly Type EnumType;

    public EnumSource(Type type)
    {
        EnumType = type;
    }


    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(EnumType);
        return (
          from object enumValue in enumValues
          select new EnumMember
          {
              Value = enumValue,
              Display = GetDescription(enumValue)
          }).ToArray();
    }


    private string GetDescription(object enumValue)
    {
        var descriptionAttribute = EnumType
                                      .GetField(enumValue.ToString())
                                      .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                                      .FirstOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;

        return (descriptionAttribute != null) ? descriptionAttribute.Description : enumValue.ToString();
    }

}


<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={my:EnumSource {x:Type my:Options}}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentOption}" SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```

You can notice I managed to get rid of the **DisplayMemberPath="Display"** by adding a ToString() method in the EnumMember class.

Is it possible to replace the **SelectedValuePath="Value"** attribute with something like a class operator (inside EnumMember) or a similar thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lot of approaches to achieve that:

### Approach 1

The `ProvideValue` method of a markup extension takes a parameter of type `IServiceProvider`, which provides, among others, a `IProvideValueTarget` service. This interface exposes property `TargetObject` which allow to retrieve the target object (combobox in your case).

You can set `SelectedValuePath` on that like this:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    IProvideValueTarget target = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
    if (target != null && target.TargetObject is ComboBox)
    {
        ((ComboBox)target.TargetObject).SelectedValuePath = "Value";
    }

    var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(EnumType);
    return (
       from object enumValue in enumValues
       select new EnumMember
       {
          Value = enumValue,
          Display = GetDescription(enumValue)
       }).ToArray();
}
```

---

### Approach 2

In case all comboboxes in your app will be binded to wrapper class `EnumMember`, you can define it under `global style of ComboBox under Application.Resources` so that you don't have to duplicate it for each and every comboBox.

Even in case, you are not binding ComboBox to enum value, SelectedValuePath can be overriden per instance.

```
<Application.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
      <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Value"/>
   </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

---

### Approach 3

You can subclass ComboBox and `OnItemsSourceChanged`, set `SelectedValuePath to Value` in case *ItemsSource is array of EnumMember class*.

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue,
                                                 IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        if (newValue != null && 
            newValue.GetType().Equals(typeof(EnumSource.EnumMember[])))
        {
            SelectedValuePath = "Value";
        }
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
```

usage in XAML:

```
<my:MyComboBox ItemsSource="{my:EnumSource {x:Type my:Options}}"
               SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentOption}"/>
```

---

On a side note sine you created own markup extension, you don't need `Binding` at all. You can bind `ItemsSource` like this:

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{my:EnumSource {x:Type my:Options}}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentOption}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do that because **SelectedValue** extract the value of specific property from **SelectedItem** based on property mentioned in **SelectedValuePath** .Means SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath works together. However If you want to do it without mentioning SlectedValuePath , then use **SelectedItem** property for Binding.

> Update this is a property in ViewModel

```
    EnumSource.EnumMember selectedItem;

    public  EnumSource.EnumMember SelectedItem
    { 
        get{return  selectedItem;}
        set { selectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");}
    }
```

> xaml

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local:EnumSource {x:Type local:DataType}}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentOption}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, though I didn't manage to get it work with SelectedItem binding. How do you specify the exact path ?

Comment: I updated the answer.See update I tried it and worked for me . You can get the value simply by SelectedItem.Value in ViewModel.